# how to track the ready state for each file with html5 xmlhttprequest object

Tags: php, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

below is my code for uploading files using XMLHttpRequest send method

```
  function send_file_to_server(file,id)
   {
     console.log('send_file_to_server id received = ' + id);
     var filename = file.name;
     var container_name = $("#gs-file-upload-container").find(':selected').text();
     var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();    
     xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e)
      {
         console.log(' bytes loaded =  '+e.loaded + ' remaining = ' +  e.total);  
      }
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
      {            
           if(xhr.status == 200 && xhr.readyState == 4){
                    on_upload_complete( filename,id,xhr);
      }

     var queryString = 'http://upload_files?filename='+filename+'&cname='+container_name;
         xhr.open("POST", queryString, true);
         xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
         xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", encodeURIComponent(filename));
         xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
         xhr.send(file);
 }
```

With the above function i wait for on_upload_complete to get called and then pass the second file object and one by one i am uploading. Can someone suggest how can i make it upload simultaneously i tried doing this below as

```
var xhr = Array();
function send_file_to_server(file,id)
   {
     console.log('send_file_to_server id received = ' + id);
     var filename = file.name;
     var container_name = $("#gs-file-upload-container").find(':selected').text();
     xhr[filename] =  new XMLHttpRequest();    
     xhr[filename].upload.onprogress = function(e)
      {
         console.log(' bytes loaded =  '+e.loaded + ' remaining = ' +  e.total);  
      }
      xhr[filename].onreadystatechange = function()
      {            
           if(xhr[filename].status == 200 && xhr[filename].readyState == 4){
                    on_upload_complete( filename,id,xhr);
      }

     var queryString = 'http://upload_files?filename='+filename+'&cname='+container_name;
         xhr[filename].open("POST", queryString, true);
         xhr[filename].setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
         xhr[filename].setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", encodeURIComponent(filename));
         xhr[filename].setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
         xhr[filename].send(file);
 }
```

by doing this i xhr[filename] inside onreadystatechange is undefined because of loop and i want to keep track of every file upload progress and finish it . But as you can see the problem is only keeping track of onreadystatechange with a unique id and i am stuck here. Please can anyone throw light , suggestions and recommendations help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have deal with Javascript Closure. `onreadystatechange` see `filename,id,xhr` of the lastest invoke of `send_file_to_server` function. To change this rewrite your function like this:

```
var xhr = Array();
function send_file_to_server(file,id)
   {
     console.log('send_file_to_server id received = ' + id);
     var filename = file.name;
     var container_name = $("#gs-file-upload-container").find(':selected').text();
     xhr[filename] =  new XMLHttpRequest();    
     xhr[filename].upload.onprogress = function(e)
      {
         console.log(' bytes loaded =  '+e.loaded + ' remaining = ' +  e.total);  
      }
    (function(localFilename, localId, localXhr){
        localXhr[localFilename].onreadystatechange = function(){  
           if(localXhr[localFilename].status == 200 && localXhr[localFilename].readyState == 4){
                    on_upload_complete(localFilename, localId, localXhr);
            }
     }
    })( filename,id,xhr)

     var queryString = 'http://upload_files?filename='+filename+'&cname='+container_name;
         xhr[filename].open("POST", queryString, true);
         xhr[filename].setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
         xhr[filename].setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", encodeURIComponent(filename));
         xhr[filename].setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
         xhr[filename].send(file);
 }
```

Comment: what is localXhr and localId ?

Comment: I have edit.
`filename,id,xhr` vars in global scope
`localFilename, localId, localXhr` vars in local scope

Comment: I am glad that my knowledge was useful)))